# Javascript Closure and async function arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, puppeteer

I been trying to search on SO, but still no luck, I need to pass the following "property" argument to the anonymous function but due to closure its not accessible.

Whats the best way to archieve this? (page is an object from Puppeteer):

```
getCssProperty: async function(selector, property) {
    await page.waitForSelector(selector);
    var val = await page.$eval(selector, x => {

        return window.getComputedStyle(x).getPropertyValue(property); <- here it does not work, undefined
    });
    return val;
},
```

Comment: "due to closure its not accessible" the code is scoped correctly, `property` is available within the callback function. That the value is `undefined` appears to be an issue with where `getCssProperty` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, from the point of view of Javascript your code is correct, `property` *should* be available in `page.$eval` callback. But page.$eval is special in that its callback is executed *in the headless browser* and is completely separate from node.js methods and variables.

So, in order to use property on that side we need to specifically pass it to the page.$eval callback.

See syntax [in the docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1):

**page.$eval(selector, pageFunction[, ...args])**

`args` are any variables we want to pass over, they must be serializable with JSON.stringify().

Therefore here's how to fix `getCssProperty`:

```
getCssProperty: async function(selector, property) {
    await page.waitForSelector(selector);
    var val = await page.$eval(selector, (x, property) => { // <-- accept here the element AND arguments

        return window.getComputedStyle(x).getPropertyValue(property);

    }, 
    property // <-- pass property over to page.$eval callback
    ); 
    return val;
},
```

Comment: Excellent Vaviloff! It worked perfectly! Thanks a lot!