# JS pass parameter in a function

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am not much skilled with JS. I want to pass the "i" variable (page's number) in the hash. I tried this but it says

> Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: i is not defined

```
async function searchResults(domain, keyword) {

  let [page, browser] = await initPuppeteer(domain)
  let products = []

  for (let i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {

    let url = `https://www.example.com/test?page=${i}`
    await page.goto(url)
    let products_page = await page.$$eval(
        '[data]',
        divs => divs.map( div => ({
            page: i <--- Need to access the outer loop iterator here
          })
        )
    );

    asins.push(products_page)
  }

  await browser.close();
  return products.flat()
}
```

Comment: Do you really mean the *hash*? If so, replace `?` with `#`. `?` starts the *query string*. `#` starts the *hash fragment*. E.g., ```let url = `https://www.example.com/#page=${i}`;```

Comment: is this puppeteer? where are you defining `asins_page`? you should have the `url` correctly as an argument, I am not a 100% sure on your $$eval statement though

Comment: what is `undefined` and when

Comment: the "page: undefined"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: Ok, I want to have the outer for loop into my hash

Comment: what a strange dupe target, where is OP trying to modify a variable inside an asynchronous function and use it outside?

Comment: I don't want to modify it. I just need to access it. I updated the code to be clearer

Comment: @sparkle the problems are very similar to each other...and now you changed the code example as well

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I checked the linked post, but in my case I don't need to modify the outerscopevar, just need to access it.

Comment: @sparkle - Sorry about that! Removed the comment. But something weird is going on, because `i` is **definitely** accessible there. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). (Please `@` ping me when you do so I can vote to reopen.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you. I have updated the code.

Comment: OK, what you posted *should* work with respect to `i`. `ReferenceError: i is not defined` should not show up when executing `div => ({ page: i  })` because the variable would be visible there. I don't know what `page.$$eval` does but I suspect *that* might be throwing an error and the name `i` is more of a coincidence. Can you try changing that to  `page: 1` or some other constant? Does it still throw an error?

Comment: @VLAZ yes, with a constant it works. page:1

Comment: Oh! This is Puppeteer code! You have to remember that the code within `$$eval` is run in a completely different place than the code surrounding it. So yes, there's no `i` in scope where that code runs. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58333846/157247) and [the docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) for what to do. Basically: https://pastebin.com/JQbv0Tgp or similar.

Comment: @sparkle *weird*. In that case, I'd guess that maybe `$$eval` is doing something odd. Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280984/how-to-use-eval-function) the second argument is a callback that's going to be evaluated in the context of the page. I suspect that perhaps $$eval is stringifying the function and then calling (essentially) `eval("divs => divs.map( div => ({ page: i  })")` which will lose access to `i`. According to the answer there, the *third* argument to `$$eval` is an argument you can pass to the function.

Comment: So you should probably pass `i` there but I'm not sure how you would need to restructure the function itself to use that argument. Perhaps `page.$$eval( '[data]', (divs, i) => divs.map( div => ({ page: i  }), i )`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah, damn. Was writing my double comment and puzzling over the documentation (*which doesn't explain how to use `...args`*. Grr!) and you beat me to it. Seems my guesswork was right, at least.

Comment: Thank you all! I tried with the @VLAZ and it's works! If you past it as an answer i will accept it! Thank you! :)

Comment: We can't post answers to closed questions. We should update the close reason to a duplicate of [the question I linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58329637/javascript-closure-and-async-function-arguments) but unfortunately SO makes that difficult. Anyway, you're sorted out now! Happy coding!

Comment: @VLAZ - Yeah, the lack of an example of using args just seems really wrong. I suppose if one had time, one could do a PR...